# Show: $\{\bar a\mid a\in m\mathbb Z\}\subset\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is equal to $\{\bar d,\bar{2d},\dots,\bar n\}$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $m,n\in\mathbb Z$, $n>0$ and $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Prove that
>   $$
> X=\{\overline a\mid a\in m\mathbb Z\}\subset \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z
> $$
>   (with $\overline a=a\mod n$) is a subgroup, and that this subgroup is equal to
>   $$
> \{\overline d,\overline{2d},\dots,\overline{n-d},\overline n\}.
> $$

I've shown that $X$ is a subgroup, by checking the properties of a subgroup (non-empty, closed, inverse element).

Given that $X$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we know that we can write $X$ as
$$
\{\overline k,\overline{2k},\dots,\overline{n-k},\overline n\},
$$
for some $k\in\mathbb N$ that divides $n$. I would like to show that $k=d$.

We know that $m\in m\mathbb Z$. Therefore $\overline m\in X$. Therefore $\overline m=\overline x$ for $x\in\{d,2d,\dots,n\}$. Since $k\vert x$, we also know that $k\vert m$.

So I've shown that $k$ is a common divisor of $m$ and $n$. But how can I show it's the greatest common divisor? Can I use contradiction here? Assume there is a greater divisor of $m$ and $n$, say $r$. Would this lead to a problem?

**EDIT**

I was given a simple solution in the chat, and I will write it out neatly here:

We can write $X=\langle\overline m\rangle$. We need to show $\langle\overline m\rangle=\langle\overline d\rangle$. It's easy to show $\langle\overline m\rangle\subset \langle\overline d\rangle$, because $m$ is a multiple of $d$. We use Bézout's identity to show $\langle\overline d\rangle\subset\langle\overline m\rangle$. Consider $\overline x\in\langle\overline d\rangle$. This means that $x$ is a multiple of $d$; say $x=rd$ for $r\in\mathbb Z$. There exists $u,v\in\mathbb Z:d=mu+nv$. So we can write $x=r(mu+nv)=rum+rvn$. This means that $\overline x=\overline{rum-rvn}=\overline{rum}\in\langle\overline m\rangle$.

Comment: You're given that $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I'm not given that it's the greatest common divisor; I have to show it. But I admit that it's a bit confusing. Thanks for the hint on Bézout's identity, I'm going to try to solve it!

Comment: The last element in $X$ should be $\overline{nd}$ (which is $\bar 0$ anyway).

Comment: @Bernard $\overline n$ is $\overline 0$ too. I think it's correct this way? It's written and proven in my book like that. The second to last element is $\overline{n-d}$.

Comment: My comment was only for the sake of consistency in notations: you can't begin with  $d,2d, 3d$ and end with $n$, even if the value is correct, from my point of view.

Comment: @Bernard ok, I've added the second to last term. I think that's the best alternative then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Use Bézout's identity: $d = mu + nv$ for some $u,v \in \mathbb Z$, to prove that $X$ contains the subgroup generated by $d$.

Comment: So we have $Y=\{kd\mid d\in\mathbb Z\}$, where $d=\gcd(m,n)$. How do I know that for each $\overline y\in Y:\overline y\in X$? We can write $y=kd=k(mu+nv)$. How do I even know that $y\in m\mathbb Z$? I don't know if $m\vert y$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a short way:**

$X$ is the ideal generated by $\overline{\!m\!}\,$ in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$:
$$\overline{\!m\!}\cdot\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z=(m\mathbf Z+n\mathbf Z)/n\mathbf Z=d\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I will need something (even more) elementary, because I'm really just now introduced to congruence classes and groups, and I can't follow this. Is there a more elementary approach to this problem, at least for now?

Comment: Which equality is a problem? It seems to me the first is a common sense observation (maybe you should give some details for it) and the second is based on the characterisation of $\gcd(m,n)$ as the positive generator of the ideal (or subgroup if you prefer) generated by $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Let's start with the first equality. We have a congruence class $\overline m$ and a group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. I haven't yet encountered that some form of multiplication is defined between those. Same for the second equality. I can see where it's coming from (Bézout's identity), but I don't even know what it means to add two groups ($m\mathbb Z$ and $n\mathbb Z$)... Besides, I don't even know what an "ideal" is, and I haven't officially been introduced to "generators" yet. So my guess is there must be a more elementary approach for me to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but you might try to think in terms of  `ring` and `ideal`  of this ring, then adapt to the tools you have at the moment. It uses very few things: multiplication defined in the same way as addition, and an ideal in a ring is only a subgroup which is further closed w.r.t. to multiples.